# Is 'disturbance on your side' idiomatic for a telephonic conversation?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Let's say I am on the phone with my friend, and due to poor reception or him being in a crowded location, it is impossible for me to hear what he is saying, Can I say

> There is a lot of noise/ disturbance on your side? Can you please speak up?

Is the use of noise/disturbance and on your side idiomatic(native speakers) here?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be!

Comment: @Mistu4u I know! But I looked it up and I did not find a lot of phrases with 'disturbance', I saw static often, which I last heard in eletrodynamics :).

Comment: I tend to say, "There's a lot of static on your end" but I'd totally understand what you mean by "disturbance"

Comment: Thor, your title would be more natural with the word *telephone* instead of *telephonic*, which sounds unusual and very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it like this, probably:

> There is a lot of noise (or ***commotion***) at your end. Can you please speak louder?

At least in the U.S., "at your end" seems more natural than "on your side." We often say things like, "on ***your end*** of the phone" (or "on *my end* of the phone").

In the context of cell phone usage, I might regard a *disturbance* as poor reception. You've asked about a noisy room, which is why I prefer *commotion*.

Comment: _Disturbance_ reminds me of Star Wars: "There is a disturbance in the Force." `;)` _Commotion_ would make me think of excitement, even if I know it could mean "sudden noisy." Is _sudden_ really what makes the difference between _commotion_ and _confusion_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I think **noise** is the difference between _commotion_ and _confusion_. (One can be confused in a silent environment, such as when you are confused by a brain teaser, or straining to remember something like a shopping list or old password.) A synonym for _commotion_ would be _din_, but, for whatever reason, I rarely hear that word in conversation. The O.P.'s _noise_ works okay, too.

Comment: As a native British English speaker I find "at your end" more natural as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any of *noise, static, interference* would be okay in OP's context, but not *disturbance*.

I think more commonly, people tend to say *"It's a **noisy** line"*. More often than not, you don't really know whether the noise is "coming from" one end or the other of the connection (and if it's not caused by the actual equipment at either end, who is to say which "side" it's coming from?).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the use of noise/disturbance and on your side idiomatic(native
>   speakers) here?

I have not heard anyone say that in England or the rest of the UK.

In circumstances where there is a lot of noise at the other person's location, people usually say something like *It's very noisy at your **end**. Please speak up* or *Please speak louder*. In this context, people normally use the word *end* instead of *side*.

In circumstances where there is poor reception/a poor signal, people usually say something like *I can't hear you properly. The line is bad* or *the line is breaking up*.

The exact wording used can vary so, people usually use these suggestions or some variation of them.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct and fine to say "disturbance on your side" in a telephone conversation.

"Disturbance on your side" means exactly what it sounds like it means, therefore it is not an idiom. It expicitly refers to a disturbance, which is on the other end of the communication line relative to the speaker.

An idiom is a phrase which either assigns a meaning to some instance of bad grammar ("catch as catch can"), or an understood meaning which is quite different from and cannot be deduced fromn the literal meaning ("kick the bucket").

Colloquially, people use "idiom" when they mean "oft-used phrase" or "canned phrase associated with a situation"; but strictly speaking, these are different concepts. Not all idioms are often used, and not all often used or canned phrases are idioms: only when their meaning is other than the literal one.

There isn't any special, often used, or preferred/expected way to express the idea "disturbance on your side", so you can be as creative as you like.